# how to make data as hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery

i m getting some data from server in json.i want to send sid from this response to some other function but dont want to display it in the browser. i tried but still its showing on the browser.
this is my js

```
$.each(responseObj.all.r,function(i){

     $('#ref').append(

        '<li>'+'<input type=hidden id="refid">'+responseObj.all.r[i].rId+'</input>'+

        '<input type="button" id="accept" value="accept">'+'</input>'+'</li>');
});
```

here is the onclick function for accept button

```
$("input[id^=accept]").click(function () {
    var p = $(this).closest('li').find('input[id^=refid]').text();
    alert(p);
    localStorage.setItem("refid",p);  
    var need=localStorage.getItem("refid");  
    accept(need);

});
```

so in output i dont want to show this refid ,i just want to send it in the accept function.thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try with [visibility property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp) for #refid

Comment: but can it be possible with <input type=hidden>?

Comment: you are not writing it as per HTML Standard. you should wrap the type in quotes. type="hidden"... and also make it self closing tag too and place value in "value"

Comment: its not making very big difference by including quotes because its working without this double code.my problem is not that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input elements are void element so this code would be invalid,

```
'<input type=hidden id="refid">'+responseObj.all.r[i].rId+'</input>'
```

So try to replace this code with this,

```
'<input type=hidden id="refid" value="'+ responseObj.all.r[i].rId +'"></input>'
```

**Note**: `id` should be `unique` . in your context you have to use same id like `id="refid"` ,`id="accept"` in each loop .so try to avoid that .instead of you have to `use class`

Asking New Question for getting input hidden value

```
$("#ref").on("click", "[type=button]", function () {

    alert( $(this).closest('li').find('input[type="hidden"]').val());


 });
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/v9W6c/6/)

Comment: but one thing now in alert box i m getting blank value see this is my onclick funtion and i m finding text of that hidden field $("input[id^=accept]").click(function () {
 var rd = $(this).closest('li').find('input[id^=refid]').text();
 var nd = $(this).closest('li').find('input[id^=nid]').text();
 alert(rd);
 alert(nd);in alert box i want to get this hidden field value..

Comment: this is possible same just by using val.see here [link](http://jsfiddle.net/v9W6c/10/)

Answer (score 0):

Add this line instead of type=hidden

style="display:none;"

Comment: Do you think it is a good practice to add such style for hidden input element?

Comment: Well i appologize for my question. but this is not at all a good practice or a standard practice to apply display:none to hidden input element. Cheers :)

Comment: There, how about that?

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like following

```
$.each(responseObj.all.r,function(i){

     $('#ref').append(

        '<li>'+'<input type="hidden" value="' + responseObj.all.r[i].rId + '" id="refid_'+ i +'" />'+

        '<input type="button" id="accept_'+ i +'" value="accept" /></li>');
});
```

You have to change your **javascript code** accordingly as per the changed markup !

Comment: @balachandran..yes i m also not using this n still getting perfect output for each i elements